# Cognito Forms: Starting from a previous PDF

Tags: cognito-forms

Can I upload a PDF instead of creating a form all from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

Cognito Forms does not currently support the ability to create forms from uploaded PDFs; however, this feature is currently proposed on the [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/MaDnylH6/6-import-form-design) and may be implemented in the future.